# How to modify spark source code and run it on cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my project I need to modify spark source code (JDBCUtils in spark-sql). I created a file with correct path `org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/JDBCUtils.scala`, modified code, and when I build and run this project locally, everything works like a charm. But when I run this jar on cluster (spark-sql dependency building as `provided`), executors are using spark-sql version, specified in classpath, instead of my modified version.

What I've already tried:

- build spark-sql dependency not as provided, replacing my version of JDBCUtils class with `MergeStrategy.preferProject` in build.sbt
- specify my jar as --jars parameter with using `spark.executor.extraClassPath`
- exclude spark-sql from classpath with spark `spark.jars.excludes` parameter
- `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` parameter

But all of these approaches didn't work.

Does anybody know the way to modify spark source code and run it remotely in cluster mode?

Comment: Why do you need to change this class in the 1st place? Wouldn't it make more sense and be easier to create a separate class?

Comment: I want to save dataframe having column with Map type, but this type doesn't supported in JDBCUtils, so I need to modify exactly this class, because it using in other places of spark internals. I have no idea, how to do this in separate class

Comment: I believe you might get useful answers if you open another question with a minimal reproducible example of what you want to achieve Vs. What Spark does by default. Looking for modifying internal Spark classes is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you Gaël, I asked another question with more specific information about task I'm trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990734/writing-dataframe-with-maptype-column-to-database-in-spark
But I think it may be a common task to modified spark source code in correspond with your needs

Comment: It's definitely not a common use case to modify Spark source code!